# Magento : Create an Account Loop in Chrome

Tags: magento-1, customer-account, register, https, chrome-browser

Website is using HTTPS. I try to create an account in frontend, it loops only in Chrome and Safari.

However, I can login in both frontend and backend.

Ive set `System > Config > Web > Cookies` :

```
Use HTTP Only: No

Cookie Lifetime : 3600
```

Still I have problem.

Comment: check data is properly posting or not from browser network

Comment: SOLUTION: Issue was fixed by deleting the 'persistent' folder within app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template (mustve been out of date coding from 1.9.2) and replacing it with the newer one from the RWD theme from v1.9.3.3 as I'd recently upgraded to 1.9.3.3.